# Как импортировать js библиотеку в jsp страницу

Tags: javascript, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

У меня есть SpringMVC проект и в jsp странице я хочу включить js файл с библиотеки. [image: library with js files]

На странице я добавил след. строку 
`<script src="resources/static/js/kurento-utils.js"></script>`
но файл не найден. Меня путь к файлу, но это не помогло.

[image]

Как это исправить ?

Comment: одно из вариантов решения [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132052/servlet-for-serving-static-content](http://%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) Надеюсь еще кому либо поможет.